# Javascript .replace() of the character " with the characters \"

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I am trying to pass a JSON string to a C# .exe as a command line argument, from Javascript as a node.js child-process. For the sake of argument my JSON looks something like this:

```
string jsonString = '{"name":"Tim"}'
```

The issue with passing this as a C# arg is that the double quotation marks must be retained if I hope to parse it in the C# code. As such, what I need to pass into the C# command line needs to look something like this, where I escape the double quotation mark:

```
string jsonStringEscaped = '{\"name\":\"Tim\"}'
```

The motivation for doing this is that it allows me to maintain a consistent object structure across the two languages, which is obviously highly desirable for me.

In order to achieve this, I am attempting to use the Javascript .replace() method prior to sending the argument to the C#, and to do this I use a simple RegEx:

```
string jsonStringEscaped = jsonString.replace(/\"/g,"\\\"")
```

Unfortunately, this returns something of the form `'{\\"name\\":\\"Tim\\"}'` which is useless to me.

I have tried variations on this:

```
string jsonStringEscaped = jsonString.replace(/\"/g,"\\ \"")
\\ returns '{\\ "name\\ ":\\ "Tim\\ "}'

string jsonStringEscaped = jsonString.replace(/\"/g,"\\\\")
\\ returns '{\\\\name\\\\:\\\\Tim\\\\}'

string jsonStringEscaped = jsonString.replace(/\"/g,"\\\")
\\ is invalid

string jsonStringEscaped = jsonString.replace(/\"/g,"\\\ ")
\\ returns '{\\ name\\ :\\ Tim\\ }'
```

I have tried variations where the second .replace() argument is contained within single quotation marks '' rather than double quotation marks "" with no success.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Better yet, can anyone suggest a more efficient method for doing what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: What is your structure that you need to launch the c# app from the command line?  It sounds as though you are trying to ad-hoc a service without any of the benefits of a service.

Comment: Are you sure that your interpretation of result is correct, and '\\' isn't just displayed form of '\'? Your replacement code seems like exactly what you need.

Comment: @Frax Thanks very much, I think this was the cause. I spent an irritating amount of time trying to debug this for such a trivial issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misreading you, I think you're just trying to escape a character that doesn't need to be escaped in your regex (").

```
var jsonString = '{"name":"Tim"}'
var escaped = jsonString.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
// escaped == "{\"name\":\"Tim\"}"
```

Comment: Perhaps I misread his question then. Seemed like he wanted to reach the format he posted - which my regex would give him- but was unable. He asked, "Better yet, can anyone suggest a more efficient method for doing what I am trying to achieve?" to which...the answer was the regex I pasted above.

Comment: One-liners are better as comments. It looks like the right code; explain a little on what it does and you'll be good.